# how to find a property is exist or not in an array in a collection?

Tags: mongodb

What query document would we use in a find() command to return all movies in the video.movieDetails collection that either won or were nominated for best picture? You may assume that an award will appear in the "oscars" array only if the movie won or was nominated.

```
"awards" : {
        "oscars" : [
            {"award": "bestAnimatedFeature", "result": "won"},
            {"award": "bestMusic", "result": "won"},
            {"award": "bestPicture", "result": "nominated"},
            {"award": "bestSoundEditing", "result": "nominated"},
            {"award": "bestScreenplay", "result": "nominated"}
        ],
        "wins" : 56,
        "nominations" : 86,
        "text" : "Won 2 Oscars. Another 56 wins and 86 nominations."
    }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include so sample documents and the expected output from that query?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this query?

```
db.movie.find({"awards.oscars.award":"bestPicture"})
```

> Input:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("569a7f590586bcb40f7d2532"),
    "awards" : {
        "oscars" : [ 
            {
                "award" : "bestAnimatedFeature",
                "result" : "won"
            }, 
            {
                "award" : "bestMusic",
                "result" : "won"
            }, 
            {
                "award" : "bestPicture",
                "result" : "nominated"
            }, 
            {
                "award" : "bestSoundEditing",
                "result" : "nominated"
            }, 
            {
                "award" : "bestScreenplay",
                "result" : "nominated"
            }
        ],
        "wins" : 56,
        "nominations" : 86,
        "text" : "Won 2 Oscars. Another 56 wins and 86 nominations."
    }
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("569a7fc60586bcb40f7d2533"),
    "awards" : {
        "oscars" : [ 
            {
                "award" : "bestScreenplay",
                "result" : "nominated"
            }
        ],
        "wins" : 12,
        "nominations" : 15,
        "text" : "Won 1 Oscars. Another 12 wins and 15 nominations."
    }
}
```

> Result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("569a7f590586bcb40f7d2532"),
    "awards" : {
        "oscars" : [ 
            {
                "award" : "bestAnimatedFeature",
                "result" : "won"
            }, 
            {
                "award" : "bestMusic",
                "result" : "won"
            }, 
            {
                "award" : "bestPicture",
                "result" : "nominated"
            }, 
            {
                "award" : "bestSoundEditing",
                "result" : "nominated"
            }, 
            {
                "award" : "bestScreenplay",
                "result" : "nominated"
            }
        ],
        "wins" : 56.0000000000000000,
        "nominations" : 86.0000000000000000,
        "text" : "Won 2 Oscars. Another 56 wins and 86 nominations."
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want this data where "_id" : ObjectId("569a7fc60586bcb40f7d2533"). .I want those records where award is bestpicture and result may be won or nominated. In Oscars array may have another property but "bestPicture" is mandatory.

Comment: You won't get that data by this query. It's explicitly matches with `bestPicture` value.

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that the bestPicture is at position 2, then we may execute the following

```
{
    "$or": [{
        "awards.oscars.2.result": "won"
    },
    {
        "awards.oscars.2.result": "nominated"
    }]
})
```

If we want to ensure wins and nominations do exist, then we probably should run

```
{
    "$and": [{
        "$or": [{
            "awards.wins": {
                "$gt": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "awards.nominations": {
                "$gt": 0
            }
        }]
    },
    {
        "$or": [{
            "awards.oscars.2.result": "won"
        },
        {
            "awards.oscars.2.result": "nominated"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Alternatively we can probably use elemMatch

```
{
    "awards.oscars": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "$or": [{
                "award": "bestPicture",
                "result": "won"
            },
            {
                "award": "bestPicture",
                "result": "nominated"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```